# Foundry console.log and emit logs not working!

Tags: solidity, foundry

Running `forge test -vv` does not show the logs, but only test passed. Only `forge test -vvvv` `shows the traces, which shows the logs.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

contract Testing is Test {
   function testLog(uint256 amount) public {
        console.log("not working", amount);
        emit log("not working too");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Foundry takes that function to fuzz thus logs will not be emitted. To fix this, remove the parameters.